# Timecop doesn't work with cucumber capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara, timecop

Sorry for my english, it's not my native language

I have some time sensetive test. It's about some alert message when before event left less than 24h or more than 24h.

> Some part of my code to find required events

```
left_less_than_24_hours_to_event = full_events_room.select{ |event| Time.now < Time.parse(event['event_time']) && Time.parse(event['event_time']) < (Time.now + 24.hours) }
left_more_than_24_hours_to_event = full_events_room.select{ |event| (Time.now + 24.hours) < Time.parse(event['event_time']) }
```

And have some cucumber scenario (fast translate to English (but it's dosen't matter about language))

```
Сценарий: User came in 2019-10-15 12:00
Допустим current date is "2019-10-15 12:00"
И go to root page
То see red message "Event Lesson-41 without room to Python-2 group"
И time return
```

I try binding.pry in my scenario and have time i really needed
[In step definitions i have time which i needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvGSZ.png)

But in the same time i binding.pry my endpoint action in controller and have another time of my system! 
[Screenshot with time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH2zQ.png)

Maybe i do something wrong? or how can i test something about time and output of browser like alert(bootstrap) messages in the same time?

This is what happen in step definitions

```
Допустим /^current date is "([^"]*)"/ do |date|
 time_to_travel = Time.parse(date)
 Timecop.travel(time_to_travel)
end

И /^time return/ do
  Timecop.return
end
```

Comment: It's unclear from your examples but are you accepting/using the browser time anywhere?  Timecop will only affect your server time, and only if you're letting Capybara run the app and tests in the same process.  If you need to mock the browser time too you need to look for a JS library to do that like sinon.js, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [travel_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html#method-i-travel_to) helper in your specs?

You said you are using Timecop but have not attached any examples.

[Here is a nice article](https://andycroll.com/ruby/replace-timecop-with-rails-time-helpers-in-rspec/) from Andy Croll about moving from a Timecop to built in helpers

Comment: [travel_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html#method-i-travel_to) was first what i try to do, and i have nothing, and after i try to use Timecop gem